# Xamarin Forms and FreshMVVM android UI issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I use to XF and FreshMVVM framework and I have a UI issue 
[image: UI issue]

My code is:

**App.cs**

```
public const string NAVIGATION_LOGIN = "NavigationContainerLogin";
        public const string NAVIGATION_MASTER_DETAIL = "NavigationContainterMasterDetail";

        private FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer _mainNav;
        private FreshNavigationContainer _loginNav;
        public App()
        {

            //prepare two navigation container
            _mainNav = CreateMasterDetailNavigation();
            _loginNav = CreateLoginNavigation();

            if (Settings.IsSignedIn)
            {
                MainPage = _mainNav;
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = _loginNav;
            }
        }
```

private FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer CreateMasterDetailNavigation()
        {
            var masterDetailNav = new FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer(NAVIGATION_MASTER_DETAIL);

```
        masterDetailNav.Init("eDocine", "hamburger.png");
        masterDetailNav.Master = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<MenuPageModel>();
        masterDetailNav.Detail = new FreshNavigationContainer(FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<HomePageModel>())
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Settings.IsDoctorUser ? DataHelper.GreenCoor : DataHelper.BlueColor,
            BarTextColor = Color.White
        };

        return masterDetailNav;
    }

    private FreshNavigationContainer CreateLoginNavigation()
    {
        return new FreshNavigationContainer(FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<ChooseUserTypePageModel>(), NAVIGATION_LOGIN);
    }
    public MasterDetailPage RootPage
    {
        get
        {
            return MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
        }
    }
```

It line appears only on Android 5+
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of this issue [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/246642/#Comment_246642)